# How do I sort by the first element of each line?

Tags: python, sorting

I am attempting to sort the first element of each line alphabetically but struggling to get this to work.

```
[['^', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'A', '!']]
[['G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'A', '!', '^']]
[['A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'A', '!', '^', 'G']]
[['T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'A', '!', '^', 'G', 'A']]
[['T', 'A', 'C', 'A', '!', '^', 'G', 'A', 'T']]
[['A', 'C', 'A', '!', '^', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T']]
[['C', 'A', '!', '^', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'A']]
[['A', '!', '^', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C']]
[['!', '^', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'A']]
```

Tried the sort and sorted function aswell as pandas but can't seem to make it work

```
with open ('BWT_test.txt','r') as seq1:
    sequence1 = seq1.read()
    seq1.read()
list1 = list(sequence1)
list1.insert(0,'^')
list1.append('!')
for seq1 in range(len(list1)):
    table1 = [list1[seq1:] + list1[:seq1]]
    sorted(table1)
    print(table1)
```

The code should organsie the list to this:

```
[['A', 'C', 'A', '!', '^', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T']]
[['A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'A', '!', '^', 'G']]
[['A', '!', '^', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C']]
[['C', 'A', '!', '^', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'A']]
[['G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'A', '!', '^']]
[['T', 'A', 'C', 'A', '!', '^', 'G', 'A', 'T']]
[['T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'A', '!', '^', 'G', 'A']]
[['^', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'A', '!']]
[['!', '^', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'A']]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: I have looked at this but can't seem to make it work, I'm new to coding I've tried both sort() and sorted() but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Is your data a list of lists? In your question it looks like many lists of lists, not one single one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Or...

```
from operator import itemgetter
sort = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(0))
```

Change the loop to this:

```
rotations = []
for seq1 in range(len(list1)):
    table1 = list1[seq1:] + list1[:seq1]
    rotations.append(table1)
rotations = sorted(rotations, key=lambda x: (x[0] not in string.ascii_letters, x[0]))
print([x[-1] for x in rotations])
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194324/discussion-on-answer-by-n-chauhan-how-do-i-sort-by-the-first-element-of-each-lin).